# NXN Alienbrain Command Line, Sync Latest

Tags: version-control, batch-file

I am trying to write a simple MS-DOS batch script to get the latest version of a project from the server.

I have tried both `ab synchronize -getlatest -i %NXN_AB_SESSION%` and `ab getlatest -i %NXN_AB_SESSION%` **HOWEVER** neither works, i.e., it just spins/waits with nothing printing to the console.

What have I missed when reading the example/documentation? I have searched the official Alienbrain forum and have also posted a question there.

Full batch script posted below.

```
::@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: Sync Alienbrain
:: Version=0.2

:ALIENBRAIN
SET NXN_AB_USERNAME=#######
SET NXN_AB_PASSWORD=#######
SET NXN_AB_SERVER=#######
SET NXN_AB_DATABASE=#######
SET NXN_AB_SESSION=ConsoleSession

:: Create new session
ab logon -i %NXN_AB_SESSION%
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO ERROR_LOGIN

:: Sync
ab synchronize -getlatest -i %NXN_AB_SESSION%
ab logoff -requestshutdown -i %NXN_AB_SESSION% 

GOTO END

:ERROR_LOGIN
COLOR 4F
ECHO Error: Alienbrain Login Failed
GOTO END

:END
ECHO.
PAUSE
COLOR
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: On further investigation, it *could* be doing something however it is not reporting any status to the console. Seriously who creates a commandline tool that does not log anything to the STDOUT. ... This is the second instance today that I've come across such a program, the first being Microsoft SyncToy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha, well I guess not many people on Stackoverflow use Alienbrain - a fact that I do not find entirely surprising because **if** I had a choice I would not use it either.

...

For future reference: the solution to this issue was to **not** use the Alienbrain Command Line client and instead roll my own 'Get Latest' C++ tool using the Alienbrain SDK.

Comment: NB: The reason for this batch script is actually to create a tool to sync Alienbrain with Perforce.